# Is it possible to set the `error` string with CheckBox?

Tags: android, android-checkbox

For `EditText`, if I set `error`, the string is displayed when the user taps the `EditText`. But if I set `error` on a `CheckBox`, can it be read? I have tried tapping the red exclamation circle, but the message was not shown.

```
myCheckBox.error = "Can the user read this error message?"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, sure you can do it, just specify this two properties in `xml` for CheckBox:

```
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
 android:focusable="true"
```

[image]

**Edit:** As you stated, if you move focus to other view, you need twice to tap to check/uncheck `CheckBox`. One tab to set focus, second to actually check/uncheck. One simple (but no elegant) solution is to set `OnFocusChangeListener` like this:

```
        chBox.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus){
                    chBox.setChecked(!chBox.isChecked());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: It does show the message, but it causes a problem. When I tap the checkbox (including the label), it does not get checked but just a grey circle is drawn on the box. I have to tap it again to check it.

Comment: Sure ? Because I've tested and 1 tap is enough on emulator. I will test also from other devices tomorrow from job. Please let me know if you fix this problem before this time.

Comment: I've tested on  real device(Android 4.4) Tablet and emulator Phone (Android 7.1.1). Both work with 1 tap.

Comment: I think it worked on your case because in your example, that ComboBox is the only view that can get focus so it always has the focus. But in my case there are other views like EditText, so the first tap just focuses the ComboBox, and the second tap checks it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, It's possibe

```
checkBox.setError("you error msg");
```

and when you want the error message to be shown call

```
checkBox.requestFocus();
```